# Iterating through a DOM with BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this DOM:

```
<h2>Main Section</h2>
<p>Bla bla bla<p>
<h3>Subsection</h3>
<p>Some more info</p>

<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
<p>Even more info!</p>


<h2>Main Section 2</h2>
<p>bla</p>
<h3>Subsection</h3>
<p>Some more info</p>

<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
<p>Even more info!</p>
```

I'd like to generate an iterator that returns 'Main Section', 'Bla bla bla', 'Subsection', etc. Is there a way to this with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Note that I can't just do soup.find_all('h2') + soup.find_all('h3') + etc. because I want to maintain the order of the tags as they appear in the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. The idea is to iterate over main sections (`h2` tag) and for every `h2` tag iterate over siblings until next `h2` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


data = """<h2>Main Section</h2>
<p>Bla bla bla<p>
<h3>Subsection</h3>
<p>Some more info</p>

<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
<p>Even more info!</p>


<h2>Main Section 2</h2>
<p>bla</p>
<h3>Subsection</h3>
<p>Some more info</p>

<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
<p>Even more info!</p>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for main_section in soup.find_all('h2'):
    for sibling in main_section.next_siblings:
        if not isinstance(sibling, Tag):
            continue
        if sibling.name == 'h2':
            break
        print sibling.text
    print "-------"
```

prints:

```
Bla bla bla


Subsection
Some more info
Subsection 2
Even more info!
-------
bla
Subsection
Some more info
Subsection 2
Even more info!
-------
```

Hope that helps.