# In BeautifulSoup how to iterate the append function?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496401/iterating-through-a-dom-with-beautifulsoup-python#), the following code iterates over the tags between two of `h2`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag


data = """<h2><name>Main Section</name><content>bla bla bla</content></h2>
<p>Bla bla bla<p>
<h3>Subsection</h3>
<p>Some more info</p>

<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
<p>Even more info!</p>


<h2><name>Main Section 2</name><content>blah...</content></h2>
<p>bla</p>
<h3>Subsection</h3>
<p>Some more info</p>

<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
<p>Even more info!</p>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for main_section in soup.find_all('h2'):
    for sibling in main_section.next_siblings:
        if not isinstance(sibling, Tag):
            continue
        if sibling.name == 'h2':
            break
        print(sibling)
```

This works wonderfully and iterates over the whole data if I use `print(sibling)` at the end. However the code breaks after a single run if I use `append`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    for main_section in soup.find_all('h2'):
        for sibling in main_section.next_siblings:
            if not isinstance(sibling, Tag):
                continue
            if sibling.name == 'h2':
                break
 -------->  main_section.content.append(sibling.extract())
```

Only the next sibling is included in the content (Even if I remove the `extract()` the same thing happens) . The output is:

```
<h2><name>Main Section</name><content>bla bla bla<p>Bla bla bla</p></content></h2>
<h2><name>Main Section 2</name><content>blah...<p>bla</p></content></h2>
```

If I run the code again, the next tag gets included within the `<content>...</content>` tags

Basically, I want to contain all the data and subsections within the `content` tag of the main section.

The output I want is:

```
    <h2><name>Main Section</name><content>bla bla bla<p>Bla bla bla</p><h3>Subsection</h3><p>Some more info</p><h3>Subsection 2</h3><p>Even more info!</p></content></h2>

    <h2><name>Main Section 2</name><content>blah...<p>bla</p><h3>Subsection</h3><p>Some more info</p><h3>Subsection 2</h3><p>Even more info!</p></content></h2>
```

1. Why does the iteration stop when I use append?
2. How do I append all the tags between the two main tags?

Comment: because u're appending to something while you're iterating over it, try to append to different list

Comment: Thanks for your idea, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Appending the tag to a new list solved my problem.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for main_section in soup.find_all('h2'):
    x = []
    for sibling in main_section.next_siblings:
        if not isinstance(sibling, Tag):
            continue
        if sibling.name == 'h2':
            break
        x.append(sibling)
    for y in x:
        main_section.append(y)
```

I was then able to add append all the siblings to the `main_section`.